# Como incluir uma regex nos parametros de uma rota do Express?

Tags: regex, node.js, express.js

Num projecto que estou a fazer quero apontar uma rota específica para um controlador. Num caso simples de uma rota com parametros eu faria assim:

```
app.get('/:lang/:activities/:activity', require('./routes/activities'));
```

Mas neste caso específico o parametro `activities` pode ter nomes diferentes em linguas diferentes e há outras rotas do site que têm 3 parametros.

Como posso combinar variações de `activities` mantendo a funcionalidade para poder usar `req.param.activities` no controlador?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Express permite ter uma [regex associada a um parâmetro](http://jilles.me/express-routing-advanced-techniques/#regularexpressions).

usando `:activities(uma_regex)` ele vai procurar fazer match e caso encontre passa esse valor para o `req.params.activities`.

## Um exemplo seria:

```
app.get('/:lang/:activities(actividades|activities|ocupaciones)/:activity', require('./routes/activities'));
```

Usando o url `/es/ocupaciones/golf` pode ir buscar-se depois no objeto `req.params` os parâmetros da url. Seria algo do tipo:

```
{ lang: 'es', activities: 'ocupaciones', activity: 'golf' }
```